# Using callback triggers with RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm writing unit tests using RhinoMocks for mocking, and now I'm in need of some new functionality which I haven't used before.

I'd like to call a function, which again will call an async function. To simulate that the async function finishes and triggers the given callback with the result from execution I assume I can use the Callback functionality in RhinoMocks, but how do I do this?

Basically what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
fakeSomething = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISomething>();
fakeSomething.FictionousFunctionSettingCallback(MyFunctionCalled, MyCallback, theParameterToGiveCallback);
var myObj = new MyClass(fakeSomething);    
myObj.Foo(); 
// Foo() now fires the function MyFunctionCalled asynchronous, 
// and eventually would trigger some callback
```

So; is there a true function I can replace this "FictionousFunction" with to set this up? Please ask if this was unclear..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just specify it using `WhenCalled`:

```
fakeSomething = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISomething>();
fakeSomething
  .Stub(x => x.Foo())
  .WhenCalled(call => /* do whatever you want */);
```

for instance, you can use the Arguments property of the call argument:

```
fakeSomething
  .Stub(x => x.Foo(Arg<int>.Is.Anything))
  .WhenCalled(call => 
  { 
    int myArg = (int)call.Arguments[0]; // first arg is an int
    DoStuff(myArg);
  });
```

It is not asynchronous. You most probably don't need it to be asynchronous, it makes your life easier anyway if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like just the functionality I'm looking for. Christmas is catching up on me here, so have to wait a few days before I get to test it.. Awaiting to accept the answer in case I have some follow up questions. Thanks again!

Comment: And no - I definitely don't want this to be async in my tests. The functionality I'm mocking is async, but I will fake it in a sync way - which is why I need to trigger another function call when the mocked function is called.

Comment: Finally tested it. This was just what I needed! Works fine - just need to add .Stub(..) after fakeSomething. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, Stub was missing, fixed it.

Comment: Hi - I 'almost' get this and think this is just what I'm looking for as well in my SL4 app's async calls. Any chance in seeing what the full test method looks like? Like what is being used for expectations or assertions? Would really appreciate it! thanks! Bill

Comment: @Bill: I don't know what you need. The expectations and assertions are the actual content of your specific test. Ask a new question if there is a specific problem.